# Pipe multiple commands to socat reverse shell (network-namespaced)

Tags: bash, network-namespaces, socat

I have a bash script that:

1. does some thing
2. connects/opens a reverse shell.
3. does another thing

`my-script` contents:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# does 'some thing'

sudo /usr/bin/nsenter --setuid 1000 --setgid 1000 --net=/var/run/netns/ns-a -- socat file:$(tty),raw,echo=0 tcp:10.10.10.1:2222

# does 'another thing'
```

Run interactively from the terminal this script stops and provides the remote shell for a user to interact with.

The use case is to have a single script that:

- accepts piped input (e.g. HEREDOC style)
- when no piped-input is given, present an interactive shell.

What I'd like to be able to do is use this script in batch files (piped input) as well as interactively.

The following has me stumped:

```bsh
my-script <<EOCMDS
echo 1
echo 2
EOCMDS
2020/12/13 21:28:59 socat[28032] E exactly 2 addresses required (there are 4); use option "-h" for help
```

Appreciate any solutions you might have in mind.

**Update:**

This is not a question about setting up a remote shell.  To avoid doubt, the remote server is setup and listening, ready to offer the (bash) shell on connection.  This question concerns the client side only.  To further remove doubt, while not relevant to this question, in practice the the remote server is not network-namespaced, only the local client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out it is not so trivial.

User input when

```bsh
$ wgsh
wgsh@vultr /$
```

and piped commands:

```bsh
$ wgsh <<EOD
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
EOD
```

Not easy, but it is doable.

The solution is to have the local `socat` open the remote shell (a reverse shell). Then drop into the background, whenever piped command input is detected. Finally, submit each piped command to the `/dev/ptsN` associated with the background `socat`.

The first problem is that `socat` always thinks it has two extra arguments whenever to try to background **within in a shell script**. Complaining:

```bsh
socat[3124] E exactly 2 addresses required (there are 4)
```

The second problem is that executing commands on another `/dev/ptsN` isn't trivial.

Consequently, the solution is in two parts:

1. Use `tmux` to background the `socat` connection.
2. Use `ttyecho` to send each piped command to the backgrounded `socat`.

`ttyecho` is a [custom utility by Pratik Sinha](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/), which also has a [Rust crate](https://docs.rs/ttyecho/0.1.2/ttyecho/).

The `ttyecho` command line tool is functionally similar to `writevt` which was part of `console-tools`, but as best I can tell development there has stopped, and the last Ubuntu package was for 12.04.

That means you'll very likely have to compile and install your own `ttyecho`.

There are some additional wrinkles - aren't there always?

Opening a new tty with `tmux` requires root privileges.
To be able to run:

```bsh
sudo --validate
tmux ...
```

without the launched process blocking for a password, you need to add to your `/etc/sudoers.d/<user>`:

```bsh
Defaults: <user> !tty_tickets
```

With all that in place, this should work (with `ttyecho` in your path)

```bsh
if [ -t 0 -a $# -eq 0 ]
then
  ## No piped commands.
 
  ## 1. Start interactive shell.
  sudo /usr/bin/nsenter --setuid 1000 \
                        --setgid 1000 \
                        --net=/var/run/netns/nns-a \
                        -- \
                        socat file:$(tty),raw,echo=0 \
                               tcp:10.10.10.1:2222
else
  ## Piped commands.
 
  ## 1. Setup sudo --validate for new tty sessions:
  # Add
  #     Defaults: <user> !tty_tickets
  # to the file (chmod 440): /etc/sudoers.d/<user>
  #
  sudo --validate

  ## 2. Start a detached connection to remote shell.
  #
  tmux new-session \
       -d \
       -s a_session \
       'sudo /usr/bin/nsenter --setuid 1000 --setgid 1000 --net=/var/run/netns/nns-a -- socat file:$(tty),raw,echo=0 tcp:10.10.10.1:2222'

  ## 3. Capture the socat process ID
  #
  SOCAT_PID=$(pgrep -u "root" socat)

  ## 4. Get the /dev/pts of the socat connection
  #
  DEV_PTS=$(tmux list-panes -t a_session -F '#{pane_tty}')

  ## 5. Consume all the piped commands
  #
  while read cmd
  do
    sudo /usr/bin/nsenter --setuid 1000 \
                          --setgid 1000 \
                          --net=/var/run/netns/nns-a \
                          -- \
                          ttyexec -n ${DEV_PTS} "${cmd}"
  done

  ## 6. Exit, if not already done.
  #
  if pgrep -u "root" socat
  then
    sudo /usr/bin/nsenter --setuid 1000 \
                          --setgid 1000 \
                          --net=/var/run/netns/nns-a \
                          -- \
                          ttyexec -n ${DEV_PTS} "exit"
  fi
fi
```

Hope that helps someone?

Answer (score 0):

For a reverse shell :

```
sudo /usr/bin/nsenter --setuid 1000 --setgid 1000 --net=/var/run/netns/ns-a -- socat TCP4:10.10.10.1:2222 EXEC:/bin/bash
```

Then execute the script in the background :

```
./my-script &
```

On the other side :

```
socat -d TCP4-LISTEN:2222 STDOUT
<commands to execute>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  As stated my remote shell connect works fine. You've reversed the local-remote sides.  So the `my-script` runs-locally and connects to the remote shell that is already listening.  I believe if you try HEREDOC commands to your 'other side' script you'll hit the same errors?

Comment: The commands are executed correctly  and the remote shell has access only to the namespace "ns-a" , there is no error ; so try out my solution for the client side.

Comment: This just hangs: `socat -d TCP4-LISTEN:2222 STDOUT <<EOD
> echo 1
> echo 2
> EOD`

Comment: To be clear "On the other side" is out of place.  This question concerns the local side only. As I said 'the remote server is setup and listening'